# Prevent Xbox users from editing Media Library

Tags: windows-media-center, xbox360

I am trying to watch some videos stored on my desktop computer on the Xbox, but they are in a format that the Xbox cannot decode, so I have to stream them through Windows Media Center. However, as soon as I set up Media Center on the Xbox, anyone can go in and browse the directory structure on my desktop. I would like to "lock" the media library so that only I can add and delete folders from my desktop computer. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I did this by re-encoding the videos using mplayer:

http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html

Now I can stream them via ustream without having to use media center anymore.  Here are some more detailed instructions for xbox 360:

http://wiki.megaframe.org/Mencoder_Transcode_for_Xbox_360